# Input text changes text/string in a script javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a `<script src` tag with an rss url that needs a word to be changed. I mean:
`<script src="http://blablabla/search=TEXT1"></script>` and the word TEXT1 needs to be the output of a `<input type="text"` input.
I have tried with lots of codes but they only work for showing and HTML not to replace a word in a `<script` tag.

Comment: And where's the code for the things you did try  ?

Comment: if your src is static, why not just do something like `var some_var='text1'; var src='http://blablabla/search=' + some_var` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can give your script tag an id like

```
<script id="foobar" ...
```

and change src attribute to input value:

```
term="your__search__value";
document.getElementById("foobar").src="http://foo.bar?search="+term;
```

you best check onchange event of your input or keyup event to grab and set value ...

Comment: Sorry, doesnt work. `<input type="text" id="foobar">
    <br>
<script id="foobar" type="text/javascript" term="your__search__value";
document.getElementById("foobar").src="http://search/?search="+term;></script>`

Comment: only id should be part of the script tag, the other part is the javascript you put itnto your onchange handler of your input and you must replace "your__search__value" with the value of the input  ...